# Should i install the programming IDE inside or outside conda environment (tensorflow 2 in windows 10)

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, environment, miniconda

I already set up everything that is required to run TensorFlow 2 on windows 10. I also did install miniconda and create an environment. I tested Tensorflow 2 library by importing it in python console and it is running like a charm. Now what I am missing is the IDE for programming.

I just wonder, where is the best place to install the IDE (such as jupyter/spyder/others)? Should I install it inside or outside the environment? From the tutorial that is spread across the internet, sometimes I found the one who places it inside the environment, and sometimes I also found the one who places it outside the environment instead.

I don't really know what are the advantages and consequences of both cases.

Comment: you could install anaconda, so there is no need to separately install IDE like jupyter/syder/ etc.and also you can install tensorflow inside the anaconda

Comment: yes, i could install anaconda and everything will installed neatly, but the reason i installed miniconda is so that i could have package for only what i need.

Comment: then you can use the command `conda install jupyter` or you can use `pip install jupyter`

Comment: sure, but my question is, where is the best place to install it? should I install it inside or outside the env (assuming that I already created one for my work)? what are the advantages and consequences of both cases

Comment: Install the jupyter in you conda env, so you can get all modules in jupyter notebook which is installed in conda env.and it is always good to use env if you are working with multiple project with diff versions of python, Tensorflow ect